# How to check whether an input device is disabled or not in xinput?

Tags: command, xinput

I can disable a keyboard or mouse using:

```
xinput disable <device>
```

But how could I know whether a device is previously disabled, in command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The man page says:

```
--disable device  
    Disable the device. This call is equivalent to 
    xinput --set-prop device "Device Enabled" 0
```

So you can use `xinput --list-props` and `grep` to find out if the device is enabled or not.

Comment: Oh, I tried that but didn't see that line, and was misleaded by another property containing "Enabled"...